# How to check the window handle is password field?

Tags: c#, c++

I have a window handle (HWND), which was captured from another process not by  the current process. Now I have to check The edit control is password field or a normal text field. can I do it successfully?

```
 I am trying with this one but always I got 0 as result.
```

uint EM_GETPASSWORDCHAR=210;

SendMessage(hWnd.ToInt32(), EM_GETPASSWORDCHAR, 0, 0);

Comment: How are you picking up any returned value?

Comment: @Bathsheba return value is int.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
LONG style = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
if( (style & ES_PASSWORD) == ES_PASSWORD ) {
    // is a password window
}
```

Comment: it gives  Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'bool' error

Comment: If you require this level of spoonfeeding, please think again if you should be doing this at all.